# Pagination in Stored Procedure with a pass through

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that that currently works for pagination.

How I use the stored procedure is, I pass a dynamic WHERE clause from MS Access so that I can filter my data.

But when I filter the data the @MaxRowNum is still counting the number of records in the table rather than the number of records with the WHERE clause added.

Is it possible to count the number of records within the WHERE clause.

This is my code so far...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FINANCIALSWHERE]
@StartRow AS INT,
@EndRow INT,
@ORGCODE AS VARCHAR(6), 
@strWHERE AS VARCHAR(256)
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Declare variables
DECLARE @MaxRowNum INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MaxRowNum = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Posting' + @ORGCODE + '

        SELECT
            x2.*
            ,@MaxRowNum as MaxRowNumber
        FROM (

            SELECT
                x1.*
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PostingID ASC) AS     RowNumber
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM dbo.Posting' + @ORGCODE + '
                WHERE ' + @strWHERE + '
            ) AS x1

        ) AS x2

    WHERE 
        RowNumber BETWEEN @STARTROW AND @ENDROW;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@StartRow INT,@EndRow AS INT, @ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @strWHERE VARCHAR (256), @MaxRowNum INT', @StartRow, @EndRow,@ORGCODE,@strWHERE, @MaxRowNum; 
END
```

I am quite new to SQL so please explain in layman terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first of the two SELECT queries inside your procedure is the issue, it seems.  The first:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MaxRowNum = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Posting' + @ORGCODE + '
```

is setting @MaxRowNum.  The WHERE clause is not appended here, so you get the @MaxRowNum equals the count of the entire table.  The simplest way to modify this code would be to change the above line to:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MaxRowNum = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Posting' + @ORGCODE + ' WHERE ' + @strWHERE + '
```

This is the same code that comprises your derived table x1.  This should give you the same count as the count in your inner query, as it is your inner query.